# How to change font size in IBM Notes 9

Tags: lotus-notes

I want to set default size from 10 to 11 when composing new messages.  I try File > Preference > Fonts and Colors, it was not I want.  I try to modify NAMEDSTYLE0, NAMEDSTYLE1, NAMEDSTYLE2 in notes.ini, it was not working.

Answer (score 2):

When composing an email, change the text so it is the font and style you want to use as the default. Select the text. Open the Text menu and select Set Current Font as Mail Default.

[image]

Source: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTWP_10.0.1/mail_default_font_t.html